# How many palindromic sequences in human genome?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing

I'm writing an article on palindromes (the words) and I wanted to mention the existence of palindromic gene sequences. Roughly how many palindromes exist in the human genome? I understand the number will vary from person to person. All I want to know is the order of magnitude. Is it 10^2, 10^3, 10^6?

Comment: Note that a DNA [_palindromic sequence_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_sequence) does not really match the usual meaning of _palindrome._ .For instance, GAATTC is a palindromic sequence, but does not match its reverse, CTTAAG.  Instead it matches the reverse of its [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity_(molecular_biology)), which is a useful biological property. ('C' is the complement of 'G', 'T' of 'A', etc.)

Comment: @mgkrebbs. Thanks for the detail. I understand it is not exactly the same, but the principle is analogous, which is fine for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The human genome [contains](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17340149) approximately 1.25*10^7 palindromes longer than 6 bp (that is 8 bp or longer). Some interesting facts are also known about their distribution.

> We found that 24 palindrome-abundant intervals are mostly located on G-bands, which condense early, replicate late, and are relatively A+T rich. In general, palindromes are overrepresented in introns but underrepresented in exons. Upstream region has enriched palindrome distribution, where palindromes can serve as transcription factor binding sites. We created a Human DNA Palindrome Database (HPALDB) which is accessible at http://vhp.ntu.edu.sg/hpaldb . It contains 12,556,994 entries covering all palindromes in the human genome longer than 6 bp.

And no, the number of shorter ones (shorter than 8 bp) isn't mentioned in the paper because they are considered unimportant, biologically.